# XCode Cocoa questions (VB.NET to Cocoa)

Tags: vb.net, cocoa, xcode

Well, I've been programming for VB.NET for a while, and now I am interested in programming Mac applications instead.

I know Objective-C alright. But, of course, I need to understand Cocoa/Xcode's development environment. I understand the Interface Builder is the equivalent to the Form Designer in VB.NET and other common concepts both environments seem to share.

Now, I will begin with something basic:

*In VB.NET, I would use the Paint function to get a Graphics object and draw a red rectangle somewhere in my window. What is the equivalent in Cocoa?*

Thank you. I know my question is quite specific (how to make a red rectangle in the window), but that is one of the few things I need to understand better since I can work from that point on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight-forward way to do something like that would be to subclass the standard view class and implement the `-[drawRect:]` method. These are handled slightly different between UIKit (iOS) and AppKit (Mac OS X). For example, to paint a red box the size of a view's visible bounds in iOS, you'd subclass `UIView` and then implement a drawRect: like so:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  [[UIColor redColor] setFill]; // set the fill color
  UIRectFill([self bounds]);    // fill a box (this view's visible bounds)
}
```

To do the same thing in Mac OS X, you'd subclass `NSView` and then implement a drawRect: like so:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
  [[NSColor redColor] setFill]; // set the fill color
  NSRectFill([self bounds]);    // fill a box (this view's visible bounds)
}
```

For more information, you can take a look at the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for working with Mac OS X and AppKit or the [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) for working with iOS and UIKit.

Comment: Where I expect [self bounds] returns a what, NSRect? Anyway, thanks, I will test this out.

Comment: @Omega - Yes, an NSRect in AppKit and it returns a CGRect in iOS

Comment: Might sound dumb but why separate that stuff in AppKit and iOS? Is there a major difference, or I can simply change all NS prefixes to UI (or CG, depending) and problem solved?

Comment: @Omega - Well, unfortunately one of the big differences between iOS and Mac OS X is how the UI is handled. AppKit is the UI framework for Mac OS X while UIKit is the UI framework for iOS (Cocoa-Touch). In many cases you can do that, but in many others you can't. Check out the drawing guides I linked in the answer, and look at the one you're most interested in starting with (iOS v Mac OS X)